# Wordpress how to filter multiple custom post_type's in a URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

In my WordPress `v5.6`, I am using the below code in Author page to show all current author's posts from a custom `post_type`, **song**.

```
<?php
$author_page_link = esc_url(get_author_posts_url(false, ID->user_nicename));
?>
<a href="' . $author_page_link . '?post_type=song">All Songs</a>
```

The above link will filter all the songs from current author with a URL below:

> `http://www.music.com/author/current_author/?post_type=song`

I want to show both "song" and "poem" custom posts from a author in the filter page.

I have tried below a links, with no luck:

```
<a href="' . $author_page_link . '?post_type=song+poem">All</a>
<a href="' . $author_page_link . '?post_type=song&post_type=poem">All</a>
```

How can I have a link to filter posts from multiple custom posts from a single author?

**Update 1**

I was using the `archive-song.php` template, that's why only the `song` custom posts are showing in the page.

When using the below URL with `?post_type=song+poem`, having `archive.php` only in template hierarchy, URL redirecting to `author.php`.

> `http://www.music.com/author/current_author/?post_type=song+poem`

And if I use the below URL with `?post_type=song&post_type=poem`, having `archive.php` only in template hierarchy, only the last `post_type` results are filtered (can be poem or song, whichever is the last query).

> `http://www.music.com/author/current_author/?post_type=song&post_type=poem`

**Update 2**

This is my author page (https://pastebin.com/kCrYebcD).
This page shows only the **latest 10 posts** from the current author of all post types.

This is my archive page (https://pastebin.com/twkWn5Bc).
Here I want to show **all the posts** from the author from all the post types.

Comment: What does your author template file look like? Could you pastebin your author.php or similar template file?

Comment: @Mikepote, your question takes me to the core of the problem. I am showing the results of the above URL query in `archive-song.php`.

Updating my question.

Comment: good stuff, but it still depends on what theme you're running because different themes can do anything they want to inside archive.php or author.php. The solution would be to modify those files to allow multiple post types to be included in the WPQuery. So post your archive.php?

Comment: See the updated notes.

Comment: I've looked at your updated notes.  It seems as though you should set some kind of parameter for your author.php archive to simply augment the query as you need. Look for that $_GET param, and do a different query based on that.  Your "Question" as this posts reads is to filter using a URL parameter, which my answer did.  It seems as though the rest of your issue is really another question all together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To include multiple Post Types via the URL parameter, you need to declare it as an array.

Your URL should look like this:

```php
echo '<a href="' . $author_page_link . '?post_type[]=song&post_type[]=poem">All</a>';
```

This should work for you.

Comment: The URL redirects to `author.php` page, not `archive.php`.

Comment: Don't you want the author.php page to be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all, looking at your code, you should be getting some errors because you're not allowed to run php code inside html without `php tags`. So if you get an error, make sure you're using the correct syntax first!

Second point in your code regarding the `custom post types`, when you first register your `custom post type` you should set the `query_var` argument to `true` if you want to use it as a `query var`.

So to register it as a `query_var` when you try to create your `custom post type` do the following: `'query_var' => true`

**AN EXAMPLE OF REGISTERING A CUSTOM POST TYPE** (pay attention to the `query_var` argument)

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_poem_post' );

function custom_poem_post(){

$args = array(
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true, ############This has to be true in order for your custom post type to be recognized by the wordpress in the url
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'poem' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'poem', $args );
}
```

If it's not a `custom post type`, then you could use the `query_vars` filter hook to register your your custom keyword, like so:

```
add_filter("query_vars", "your_custom_query_vars");

function your_custom_query_vars($vars){
  $vars[] = "your_keyword_to_register_as_query_var";
  return $vars;
}
```

Then wordpress will recognize it as a `query var` and you could do whatever you want with it.

Comment: `'query_var'  => true,` is already set and I noticed it has no impact.